# NSCalendar dateFromComponents: gives unexpected results

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

I'm trying to write a method that takes an `NSDate` as input and returns the first day of the week that the date falls in. I've been using `NSDateComponents` to try and set the year, week of year, and day of week; but I get unexpected behavior. For example :

```
NSDateComponents* comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
[comps setYear:2015];
[comps setWeekday:1];
[comps setWeekOfYear:1];
NSLog(@"%@\n%@\n\n", comps, [formatter stringFromDate:[calendar dateFromComponents:comps]]);
```

Results in:

```
<NSDateComponents: 0x7fbc24cc9870>
Calendar Year: 2015
Week of Year: 1
Weekday: 1
Dec 27 2016
```

All strangeness aside, here is my method that's supposed to return the first day of the week from an `NSDate`:

```
- (NSDate *)dateAtBeginningOfDayForDate:(NSDate *)inputDate
{
    // Use the user's current calendar and time zone
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    [calendar setTimeZone:timeZone];
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:inputDate];
    NSDateComponents* startOfWeek = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
    // Set the time components manually
    [startOfWeek setWeekOfYear:dateComps.weekOfYear];
    [startOfWeek setYear:dateComps.year];
    [startOfWeek setWeekday:0];
    // Convert to date
    NSDate *beginningOfDay = [calendar dateFromComponents:startOfWeek];
    return beginningOfDay;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Ry’s Objective-C Tutorial...

http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/dates